# ksh: appending date-time in history

Tags: date, ksh, command-history

Does anyone have a solution to append date and time to this as another column?  It seems like it would be very useful with sorting, etc...

```
$ history
3   history
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ksh93` shell does not support modifying the shell's history file format in the way that you require, like some other shells do (`zsh` and `bash`, for example).